# Spring Boot Live Reload always asks for password after changes within the templates and static folders

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, livereload

I use thymeleaf, devtools and spring security in my spring boot application.

When I make changes within the "/static" or "/templates" folder, the browser refreshes the page (and I do see the changes). Thus, live reload is working.

But after another 2-3 seconds, it redirects me always to the login form and asks me for the username and password.

Is there a way to keep the session upon template changes? Entering the username & password all the time makes the development slow.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it at and the solution was prettyeasy:

I recognized there was an info in my log stating "Cannot serialize session attribute SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT for session". I noticed my "Role" domain, which I used in the implementation of UserDetails, did not implement the Serializable interface. I just had to implement that and it worked. Now, the session is not destroyed after a live reload and the user keeps logged in.